# How does streaming operator unpacking work?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

Consider the following code:

```
  wire unpacked_wire[3:0];
  wire [3:0] packed_wire;

  assign     unpacked_wire   = packed_wire; // Error: Cannot assign packed type to unpacked type
  assign {>>{unpacked_wire}} = packed_wire; // No errors
```

My first assignment statement errors out. However, the second one doesn't. However, according to the IEEE Std 1800-2017, sec 11.4.14:

> When used in the left-hand side, the streaming operators perform the reverse operation, i.e., unpack a stream of bits into one or more variables.

So isn't the streaming operator on the LHS redundant since its converting an unpacked type... to an unpacked type? So shouldn't this second assignment still be illegal? To me, this code reads like the streaming operator is actually *packing* the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *unpacking* in the sense that it is taking a single integral packed value and breaking it up into the individual elements of an unpacked array. When it comes to the streaming operator, whether it is *packing* or *unpacking* is not so relevant—it is reorganizing the layout of the bits.
You could also write this as

```
assign unpacked_wire   = {>>{packed_wire}};
```

When there is only one object on either side of the assignment, it doesn't matter which side you put the streaming operator on.

The LRM considers unpacked types a *strong* type. You can only make assignments from/to equivalent types. Packed types on the other hand are *weak*. You can make assignments between packed types of different sizes and it silently truncates or pads the data. The streaming operator is more like an explicit cast that facilitates assignments between unpacked and other packed or unpacked types.

Comment: So is it correct to think of streaming operators as converting its operand to a bit-stream, AND temporarily relaxing the packed / unpacked assignment restrictions? I mean, I know they do more than that, but do they at least do that?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by the streaming operator behaves like a cast. There is also an explicit bit-stream cast (Section _6.24.3 Bit-stream casting_ in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595))